# Getting getElementById is Undefined

Tags: javascript, html

Here's my code:

```
<html>
<header>
<title>Checkup Date</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
function datechange() {
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject

("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");

  }

var tr = getElementsById(nameUpdate)
var tds = tr.getElementsByTagName('td');
var user = "";
var date = "";
for(var i = 0, len = tds.length; i < len; ++i) {
    user = tds[0];
    date = tds[3];
}


var url = "changedate.psp"
var params = "user=" + user + "&date=" + date;

xmlhttp.open("GET", url + "?" + params, true);
xmlhttp.send();
xmlDoc=xmlhttp.responseXML;

}

</script>
</header>

<body>

<%
Python that doesn't matter
%>

<%= More Python %>

</body>
</html>
```

My outputted HTML:

```
<tr id="TL-D03">
<td>nobody</td>
<td>TL-D03</td>
<td>2010-01-01</td>
<td>
<input type="checkbox" onclick="var nameUpdate = 'TL-D03'; datechange();">
```

**What am I doing wrong here? It says getElementById is undefined.**

Comment: why would you do `var nameUpdate = 'TL-D03'; datechange();`? Pass it as a argument to the function!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`getElementById` is a function of `document`:

```
var tr = document.getElementById("nameUpdate")
```

**MDN**: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.getElementById

Comment: That worked, but now it says nameUpdate isn't defined! Oy vey!

Comment: `nameUpdate` should be in quotes - it's a string, not a variable.

Answer (score 1):

It's `document.getElementById()`, not `getElementsById()`, as it only returns one element.

The latter would not be very useful, since `id` attributes must be unique within an HTML document.

Answer (score 1):

Problem 1: you're calling `getElementsById`. IDs are unique: the function is `getElementById`. No `s`.

Problem 2: `getElementById` is not a global function. You need to call it on the document object:

```
var tr = document.getElementById(nameUpdate)
```

After all, your script could reference more than one document (for example, with an `iframe`), so you need to be explicit about where you expect the element to be.

Answer (score 1):

Also try changing:

```
<input type="checkbox" onclick="var nameUpdate = 'TL-D03'; datechange();">
```

to this:

```
<input type="checkbox" onclick="datechange('TL-D03')">
```

and

```
function datechange() {
```

to this

```
function datechange(nameUpdate) {
```

makes more sence

Answer (score 0):

you need to use `document.getElementById("yourelementid")`

Answer (score 0):

The reason it doesn't work is that `var` scopes a variable to the function it is defined in, so it isn't readable outside the anonymous function assigned to the onclick handler.

In more general "wrongness" terms, passing data about using globals is generally a bad idea.

Pass it as an argument instead.

```
function datechange(nameUpdate) {
```

and

```
datechange('TL-D03');
```

Comment: Hrm, now it tells me that tr is null.